# WPF handle Pinch Zoom on Touchpad

Tags: wpf, events, textblock, touchpad

I have a WPF `TextBlock`. I am controlling the font size by using `ManipulationDelta`, to simulate zooming in/out. It's currently in a very crude way, but it works.

This works for a touchscreen, but I want the same behaviour to work on my laptop touchpad - i.e. two-finger pinch-zoom.

What's the event I need to hook into to make this work?

The touch code is as follows:

```xml
 <TextBlock Name="txbl_displaySong" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Lucida Console" 
    FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Path=T.SelectedSong.TransposedChordsOverLyrics, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Padding="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsManipulationEnabled="True" 
    ManipulationDelta="txbl_displaySong_ManipulationDelta" 
    ManipulationCompleted="Txbl_displaySong_ManipulationCompleted"
    TouchDown="Txbl_displaySong_TouchDown" 
    MouseDown="Txbl_displaySong_MouseDown"/>
```

Code Behind:

```vb
Dim isPinchIn As Boolean = False
Dim isPinchOut As Boolean = False
Dim prevScale As Double = 0
Private Sub Txbl_displaySong_ManipulationCompleted(sender As Object, e As ManipulationCompletedEventArgs)
    prevScale = 0
    isPinchIn = False
    isPinchOut = False
End Sub

Private Sub txbl_displaySong_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaEventArgs)
    Dim tScale As Double = e.CumulativeManipulation.Scale.Length
    If (prevScale > 0) Then
        isPinchIn = isPinchIn OrElse prevScale > tScale ' if same scale, assume no change
        isPinchOut = isPinchOut OrElse prevScale < tScale ' if same scale, assume no change
    End If
    prevScale = tScale

    Dim mCount As Integer = e.Manipulators.Count
    ...
    If mCount = 2 Then
        If isPinchIn Then
            txbl_displaySong.FontSize = Math.Max(6.0, txbl_displaySong.FontSize - 0.2) ' limit to 6
        ElseIf isPinchOut Then
            txbl_displaySong.FontSize = Math.Min(40.0, txbl_displaySong.FontSize + 0.2) ' limit to 40
        Else
        End If
    End If

End Sub
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I figured out a workaround which half solves it:

Wire up some code to the MouseWheel event:

```
    private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
            ...
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
            ...
    }
```

With my touchpad, I get a Delta of either 120 or -120 depending on whether I'm pinching to zoom in or pinching to zoom out.